# Spring can't connect to database when started by Monit

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, spring-security, monit

I have a Jetty 6 server running a grails 1.1 (which in turn uses hibernate) application. Since sometimes it goes down, I'd like it to automatically restart if something happens. So, I heard about Monit and decided to give it a try. I've created the following configuration:

```
check process jetty with pidfile /var/run/jetty.pid
  group nfetron
  start program = "/data/ebs/NFeTron/bin/jetty.sh start"
  stop program = "/data/ebs/NFeTron/bin/jetty.sh stop"
  if failed host "localhost" port 8090 protocol HTTP with timeout 10 seconds then restart
  if mem usage > 95% for 11 cycles then restart
```

Well, the problem is that when the Monit starts the Jetty, it doesn't run normally. It fails to connect to the database, as seen in the following log:

```
2017-02-13 21:35:34.356::INFO:  jetty-6.1.14
2017-02-13 21:35:34.404::INFO:  Deploy /data/ebs/NFeTron/contexts/javadoc.xml -> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler@153f5a29{/javadoc,file:/data/ebs/NFeTron/java$
2017-02-13 21:35:34.536::INFO:  No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2017-02-13 21:35:34.875::INFO:  No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2017-02-13 21:35:35.404::INFO:  No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2017-02-13 21:35:37.337:/NFeTron:INFO:  Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
loading security config ...
2017-02-13 21:35:54.383::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@770c2e6b{/NFeTron,file:/data/ebs/NFeTron/webapps/NFeTron/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springfr$
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactor$
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception $
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        ... 3 more
2017-02-13 21:35:54.384::WARN:  Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bea$
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2017-02-13 21:35:54.390::INFO:  Opened /data/ebs/NFeTron/logs/2017_02_13.request.log
2017-02-13 21:35:54.456::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8090
```

I searched a lot and couldn't find anyone facing the same problem. When I start the application using SSH (with root user), it works normally. But when Monit starts it (supposedly with root user), it doesn't. Does anyone have any clue about this problem?

Comment: Jetty 6 is EOL (End of Life)

Comment: Note: the stacktrace is entirely within Spring, and Jetty is only involved in that it is reporting that Spring failed to load during init of the WebApp.